# Using command substitution to execute multiple commands

Tags: command-line, bash

What I am trying to do in bash is write a script, `foo`, that when I run `$(foo)`, it changes the directory and runs a script using `source`. The contents of `foo`:

```
echo cd bar
echo "&&"
echo source baz
```

When I run `$(foo)`, it changes directory to "bar", but it does not run `source baz`. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Plus, why would you want to do that? This seems a little contrived and I'm sure there are better ways to achieve what you need.

Comment: @slhck I can't affect the shell from inside a script or program. The only ways to affect the shell are with command substitution or `source`, so I'm trying to find a way to do that.

Comment: Why are you storing the commands to execute in a variable in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `eval` the output:

```
eval $(foo)
```

Otherwise, `&&`(or any other similar language element) is treated as if it were wrapped in quotation marks: a regular argument to `cd`.

```
$ echo $(foo)
cd bar && source baz
```

Skipping the leading `echo`, this would execute `cd` with the four arguments `bar && source baz`, silently dropping all but the first.

Comment: Note that, depending on your application, this might not be a really good idea.

Comment: Seems to work, if not the most elegant solution. Thanks.

Comment: Which language arguments are treated like they're in quotes? Or is just everything literal except for the first word?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aliases](http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html) (see also: [man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)) to do what your trying to do.

```
alias foo='cd bar && source baz'
```

will change directory to bar and source baz when you execute foo.